# Блокирование кнопки submit после выполнения своей функции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма обратной связи и собственно кнопка отправки -

```
<div class="form-group"><button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-autoxl">Oтправить</div>
```

Есть скрипт, который все это обрабатывает -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /*
        Contact form
    */
    $('.contact-form form input[type="text"], .contact-form form textarea').on('focus', function() {
        $('.contact-form form input[type="text"], .contact-form form textarea').removeClass('input-error');
    });
    $('.contact-form form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.contact-form form input[type="text"], .contact-form form textarea').removeClass('input-error');
        var postdata = $('.contact-form form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/contact.php',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.nameMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form .contact-name').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if(json.emailMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form .contact-email').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if(json.messageMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form textarea').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if(json.nameMessage == '' && json.emailMessage == '' && json.messageMessage == '') {
                    $('.contact-form form').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $('.contact-form').append('<p>Спасибо за обращение!</p>');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Проблема в том, что кнопку можно нажать несколько раз до того, как форма исчезнет и появится текст - `Спасибо за обращение!`, и сколько раз кнопку нажали, столько раз и отправится письмо на ящик.

Я пытался фиксить это скриптом, чтобы кнопка была недоступна после нажатия пару секунд. Именно за это время сервер успевает обработать форму и сообщить либо об удачной отправке сообщения, либо об ошибке. Сам скрипт -

```
$(function() {

    $('#send').click(function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);

      setTimeout(function(){
          $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
      },2000);

    });


});
```

И кнопка была недоступна 2 секунды после каждого нажатия, однако она просто перестала выполнять свою функцию отправки данных. А в чем проблема, понять не могу.

Comment: Ставьте `disable` по клику и снимайте его как получите ответ от сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам помогут обработчики beforeSend, complete и error.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/contact.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.nameMessage != '') {
                $('.contact-form form .contact-name').addClass('input-error');
            }
            if(json.emailMessage != '') {
                $('.contact-form form .contact-email').addClass('input-error');
            }
            if(json.messageMessage != '') {
                $('.contact-form form textarea').addClass('input-error');
            }
            if(json.nameMessage == '' && json.emailMessage == '' && json.messageMessage == '') {
                $('.contact-form form').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $('.contact-form').append('<p>Спасибо за обращение!</p>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: К сожалению Ваш способ не очень помог, кнопка блокируется на сотую секунды и снова активна. ~2 раза успеваю нажать перед отправкой, и приходит 2 письма. Возможно ли заблокировать кнопку на пару секунд?

Comment: @Danya setTimeout(func, delay)